# how multiple underscores in a for loop work

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to understand the code from this website:
https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/end-to-end-speech-recognition-pytorch

```
for (waveform, _, utterance, _, _, _) in data:
```

Can someone please explain,what is the meaning of the above line and how it works ?
Like are we ignoring some values while unpacking the data or something else.

Complete code for the function:

```
def data_processing(data, data_type="train"):
    spectrograms = []
    labels = []
    input_lengths = []
    label_lengths = []
    for (waveform, _, utterance, _, _, _) in data:
        if data_type == 'train':
            spec = train_audio_transforms(waveform).squeeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
        elif data_type == 'valid':
            spec = valid_audio_transforms(waveform).squeeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
        else:
            raise Exception('data_type should be train or valid')
        spectrograms.append(spec)
        label = torch.Tensor(text_transform.text_to_int(utterance.lower()))
        labels.append(label)
        input_lengths.append(spec.shape[0]//2)
        label_lengths.append(len(label))

    spectrograms = nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(spectrograms, batch_first=True).unsqueeze(1).transpose(2, 3)
    labels = nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(labels, batch_first=True)

    return spectrograms, labels, input_lengths, label_lengths
```

Comment: It is a value unpacking, please refer to https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/ . underscore is just an interpretation which tells you (based on tutotial material) that you do not need that element.

Comment: Now I got the idea, Thank you so much for helping.